# Inviting Facebook friends to app

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, api

Is it possible to use the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) to programmatically send an app invitation (or `apprequest`) to a user's friends?

I would very much like to avoid using [Facebook's UI for this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) and integrate it with my own look and feel. Namely, this code won't suffice:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Your Message diaolog'
});
```

I would like to use a `FB.api` call.

If this isn't possible, what other options do I have to allow a user to invite their Facebook friends? I can't access the friends' emails, so that's out of the question.

Thanks!